# Explorer.exe hangs on right click. Please help me analyze this dmp file

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am running Windows 10, 64 bit.

Whenever I am using windows explorer and right click on any file the program hangs which turns the mouse into an endless circle and if I click again on the program it stops responding. I tried using shexview.exe to troubleshoot the problem and disabled all 3rd party context extensions and that did not solve the issue.

If someone could take a look at this dmp file and give me a clue on what is causing it to hang I would be super happy as its getting rather frustrating lol. THANKS!

Link to dmp file: [DMP FILE](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiPgBYIFBc8vhzciU4SeUwZZnlCo)

okay so the second i was gonna post this, right clicking in explorer.exe doesn't cause it to hang anymore. It is possibly because I opened task manager and ended a few windows processes that were running...but if you guys could still check out the dmp file so in the future i can know what the issue was that'd be great.

Comment: explorer hangs at QueryViewService when doing LPC/COM calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply andre, not sure exactly what that means. I did a quick google search on it and it did not come back with many results so far.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Procedure_Call, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

Comment: Thanks for the links, but any idea on how to fix this? I am getting this same error once again and it is just so frustrating.

Comment: update to Version 1607 and look if it is fixed

Comment: Done. So far everything is working again! Hopefully this fixed the problem for good. Before I updated to 1607, when restarting my computer it temporarily fixed the issue as well. It seems to only be an issue after the computer had been running for awhile.